# Subtracting terms from a Fourier series

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

It is known that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ in $]0,\pi]$, mostly because this is a way of evaluating $\zeta(2)$. Knowing this, is there a way to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{2n}$? It's an exercise in one of my professor past papers, and he talks about "antisimmetric part" of a function. I suspect that it is possible to do something similar to what can be done with matrices, but I have no idea why or how. Anyone?

Comment: Also, you can't include $0$ here: the identity fails then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface, all that happened was plugging $2x$ instead of $x$, and dividing the sum by $2$. Which results in
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{2n} = \frac12 \frac{\pi - 2x}{2},\quad x\in (0,\pi) \tag1$$
However, this only works because  the original identity 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2} \tag2$$
was true on the larger interval $x\in (0,2\pi)$. (This latter fact does involve some symmetry consideration: replacing $x$ by $2\pi -x$ changes the sign of both sides.)

In general: if something like (2) is true in some interval $I$, and we have an invertible  transformation $x=f(t)$, $t=f^{-1}(x)$, then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n f(t))}{n}=\frac{\pi-f(t)}{2}  $$
holds in $f^{-1}(I)$. And we can rename $t$ as $x$ if we want. It's not something about Fourier series, just a manipulation of symbols.

Comment: Is it legit to do so? What I mean is: if I come across a linear change of variables like the one above, can I always do something like that?

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis The answer to "can I always" is always *no*. One has to keep the brain engaged. Certainly, if an identity holds for something called "$x$". Then it holds with "$2x$" in that place. However, one has to consider the domain of $x$.  I'll add a remark to the answer about this.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!